# Illegal assignment from List<AggregateResult> to List<Aggregateresult>?

Tags: apex

```
public class Aggregateresult {

    public static void aggregateresults()
    {
        aggregate result[] results = [select count(id) records,name from account group by name having count(id)>1];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a namespace collision. Change the name of your class from `Aggregateresult`.

Since Apex is a case-insensitive language, the compiler sees this as the same as the built-in class `AggregateResult`. The SOQL query is known to return a `List<AggregateResult>`, as in the built-in class, but your local variable `results` is being read as a `List<Aggregateresult>`, as in the class you're writing here. Since those are different types, an error results.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer... I have a class with name as aggregateresult in my organisation, so it is not able to identify it properly..
Worked fine after deleting that aggregateresult class.

```
public class Aggrresulstduplicate
{
     public static void aggres()
     {
          aggregateresult[] results = [select count(id) records,name from account group by name having count(id) > 1];
          system.debug(results.size());
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the same answer as what David Reed provided. If you found his answer useful, you should consider making his answer "Accepted". This will give both you and him reputation points. One you have enough reputation, you'll also be able to upvote other people's answers. While both actions (accepting answers, and upvoting) are voluntary, doing so is encouraged because it helps other people with similar problems to identify which answers are useful.